# Cypress: Mocha Automation Framework: Custom Command : Custom Command not running not running in test

Tags: automated-tests, mocha.js, cypress

I created a custom command that would automate the process of of adding an item to shopping cart.  I ran rand the code in the test PRIOR to add it to the custom command and it worked perfectly.  I add the code 'add to shopping cart' code and created the custom command called `AddToCart`.  I added the command to my test spec file and tried to run the test.

Although, the raw automation code is correct, because I created and ran it in the test successfully in the test spec file, it won't run it won't perform as a  custom command, so the test hangs and won't add the item to the shopping cart.   You can watch it [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/86qrxdmysvblmj5/custom%20command%20problem.mp4?dl=0)

I I've been looking at this code and I'm utterly confused what I might have gone wrong.  I'd love another pair of eyes to take a look at it.

thanks in advance.

I'm totally confused how this could happen

Test spec with custom command

```
> /// <reference types="Cypress" />
>  
>      describe('My test feature',function() {
>  
>     beforeEach(function(){
>        cy.fixture('example').then(function(data){ 
>  
>              this.data=data 
>  
>             })
>  
>     })
>  
>     
>  
>     it('my first test scenario', function(){
>    
>         cy.visit('https://rahulshettyacademy.com/angularpractice/')
>         cy.get('input[name="name"]:nth-child(2)').type(this.data.name)
>         cy.get('select').select(this.data.gender)
>  
>         cy.get('input[name="name"]:nth-child(1)').should('have.value',this.data.name
> )  
>         cy.get('input[name="name"]:nth-child(2)').should('have.attr', 'minlength','2')
>         cy.get('input[id=inlineRadio3]').should('be.disabled')
>  
>         //custom command
>         cy.get('a[href="/angularpractice/shop"]').click()
>         cy.AddToCart('blackberry')
>       
>  
>    
>      })//end of test case 
>    
>  
>  
>      })//end of describe
```

The custom Command

```
> // *********************************************** // This example
> commands.js shows you how to // create various custom commands and
> overwrite // existing commands. // // For more comprehensive examples
> of custom // commands please read more here: //
> https://on.cypress.io/custom-commands //
> *********************************************** // // // -- This is a parent command -- // Cypress.Commands.add('login', (email, password)
> => { ... }) //   Cypress.Commands.add("AddToCart", (productName) => { 
>  
>     cy.get('h4.card-title').each(($e1, index, $list) =>{//this go the the array of items for sale using an array
>  
>         if($e1.text().includes(productName))//find the product in the script
>       
>         {
>               cy.get('button.btn.btn-info').eq(index).click()//when you have found the product 'add to cart' button
>     
>         }
>     })   })
>     // // -- This is a child command -- // Cypress.Commands.add('drag', { prevSubject: 'element'}, (subject,
> options) => { ... }) // // // -- This is a dual command -- //
> Cypress.Commands.add('dismiss', { prevSubject: 'optional'}, (subject,
> options) => { ... }) // // // -- This will overwrite an existing
> command -- // Cypress.Commands.overwrite('visit', (originalFn, url,
> options) => { ... })
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this condition: `if($e1.text().includes(productName))` inside your custom command? I mean I can see "Blackberry" in the video but "blackberry" is your parameter:

[image]

```js
cy.AddToCart('blackberry')
```

Case matters, so typing `cy.AddToCart('Blackberry')` might solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I don't think this was your intention but '...might solve your problem'  initially came across as abrupt. However, its possible to misinterpret something in written form as there is no vocal pitch and tonality.   Still I really appreciate you taking the time to help solve this problem.  Something I will be aware of from this point on.

Comment: @fypnlp: that was only your interpretation of the written text. "might" was simply used in its most common meaning, that is injecting some uncertainty into the sentence, which was my intention to say it like that since I don't really sit at your laptop and there could be another problem that I'm not aware of.

Comment: You have one perspective and I have another.   We can agree to disagree on a subjective interpretation - it's not that deep.  Have a great day.

Answer (score 1):

You can use create a case-insensitive search with a regex. The easiest way is with a `.contains()` command.

Also, target the whole card instead of the heading, `.contains()` will find text in all children of the card. Then the button is easier to find.

```js
it('adds an item to the cart', () => {

  Cypress.Commands.add("AddToCart", (productName) => {

    cy.contains('div.card', new RegExp(productName, 'i'))
      .each($card => {
        cy.wrap($card)
          .find('button').contains('Add')
          .click()
      })
  })

  cy.viewport(1200,1200)
  cy.visit("https://rahulshettyacademy.com/angularpractice/shop");

  const productName = "blackberry";

  cy.get('a').contains('Checkout ( 0 )')
  cy.AddToCart(productName)
  cy.get('a').contains('Checkout ( 1 )')

});
```

Comment: that's fantastic I will definitely add that modification to my code. It makes perfect sense.  I'm going to refer to this layout of the code as it's better than the one in my training material.  Thank you so much